# What does Number of leaves and Size of tree mean in Weka?

Tags: weka, decision-tree, j48, c4.5

Could someone explain in plain English what the number of leaves and size of tree mean in Weka? I have made my decision tree, and this is what I got below, but I just need an explanation of what these values mean. Thank you.

Number of leaves: 49;
Size of tree: 87.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of leaves is he number of terminal nodes, i.e. the ones that have no branches after them. These are in rectangles in the Weka tree diagram.

The size of the tree is the total number of nodes in the tree, which is terminal nodes + nonterminal nodes.  For my example below, Weka reports

```
Number of Leaves  :     4

Size of the tree :  6
```

[image]